# Unable to integrate Tomcat with solr

Tags: java, mysql, apache, tomcat, solr

I am trying to integrate Tomcat-7 with solr-4-4-0.

I followed all the instructions [here](http://gregsomers.com/blog/2013/07/30/install-apache-solr-44-on-ubuntu-1204-with-tomcat-7-and-mysql-data-import). But when navigating to the given url i.e "localhost:8080/manager/html", the connection is getting timed out. My solr is working fine. I restarted solr, but it didn't help.

On running tomcat I'm getting the following Error:

```
nish@styx:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin$ ./startup.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat7/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
touch: cannot touch `/usr/share/tomcat7/logs/catalina.out': No such file or directory
./catalina.sh: 389: ./catalina.sh: cannot create /usr/share/tomcat7/logs/catalina.out: Directory nonexistent
```

Following are the contents of my /var/log/tomcat/

```
COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
apache2  1977     root    3u  IPv4  13706      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
apache2 11743 www-data    3u  IPv4  13706      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
apache2 11744 www-data    3u  IPv4  13706      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
apache2 11745 www-data    3u  IPv4  13706      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
apache2 11746 www-data    3u  IPv4  13706      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
apache2 11747 www-data    3u  IPv4  13706      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
apache2 19483 www-data    3u  IPv4  13706      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
firefox 20476     nish   66u  IPv4 875088      0t0  TCP styx.local:54982->93.184.216.119:http-alt (SYN_SENT)
firefox 20476     nish   87u  IPv4 878854      0t0  TCP styx.local:54983->93.184.216.119:http-alt (SYN_SENT)
apache2 26468 www-data    3u  IPv4  13706      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
```

Could someone please help me fix this? Thanks

Also, localhost:8080 is working but lsof -i:8080 shows multiple processes, and I'm not sure if tomcat is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You are running the startup script as a nish user and your nish user does not have access to the directories mentioned in your error log below /usr/share/tomcat7, hence tomcat is not started, hence the timeout error

Either run tomcat as root or put tomcat in a directory where it can create the needed directories

Comment: root@styx:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin# ./startup.sh

Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat7

Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat7

Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat7/temp

Using JRE_HOME:        /usr

Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
touch: cannot touch `/usr/share/tomcat7/logs/catalina.out': No such file or directory
./catalina.sh: 389: ./catalina.sh: cannot create /usr/share/tomcat7/logs/catalina.out: Directory nonexistent
root@styx:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin#